# Is a list of selected packages stored in the file system?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg, backup

I have a backup of my Ubuntu computer stored on my iMac. My hard disk died and I want get a list of the packages that was installed by just reading from the file system and without running commands like `dpkg --get-selections`

Comment: What's wrong with `dkpg --get-selections`?

Comment: I do not have shell access to the machine, because my machine is broken and I just have the file system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it by reading `/var/lib/dpkg/status` from your backup.

In my running Ubuntu:

```
grep '^Package:' /var/lib/dpkg/status | cut -f2 -d' '
```

Comment: Nice edit, I was about to point you [here](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)

Answer (score 3):

`grep "Package" /var/lib/dpkg/status > Package.list` should do the trick